# How can I transfer data to cyclone 4?

Tags: fpga, cyclone

I have the fpga below, I managed to implement a couple of simple designs. According to the manual it should be possible to foward data from my laptop to the fpga using the usb-blaster cable, I cannot manage to find any example that would show me how to do it. I haven't touched fpga in ages, I have used a virtex 5 ages ago. Back then I transferred data serially, but I do remember It was also possible through ethernet.

Is there an easy way to do the same thing here? You can assume I have exactly what's in the picture.

Any other alternative will be fine, as long as I can transfer data between my pc and the fpga.

[image]

Comment: Define "data".  Are you referring to FPGA configuration data, application data?  If it is application data, is a single transfer or a stream, what is the data, what data rate is required?

Comment: Something really simple, say I've an adder or a multiplier implemented. I just wanna transfer the operands I might have stored in my pc.

Comment: Create a serial port in your FPGA design and connect the pins to a 3.3V level USB -> serial adapter.  Or, it looks like there may be a rs-232 serial level shifter on your board, use that.

Comment: How do I create a serial port? What about if I wanted to transfer stream instead? (just out of curiosity).

Comment: Your board should have come with VHDL/Veralog examples for creating a serial port, if not, google VHDL Serial port and you'll find sample implementations.  Digilent has lots of examples online for their FPGA boards that you could port.

Comment: What about the stream instead?

Comment: Is that an Ethernet port top right? More complex than RS-232 but much higher performance.

Comment: @BrianDrummond No, that's PS/2. The connector in the lower right is VGA, and the USB port is power-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get bulk data in/out of a design on your FPGA will be to implement a UART and hook it up to the RS232 port on your board. Unless your computer has a serial port (what is this, 1995?), you will need a USB/serial adapter.

For very simple designs, you may want to ignore the computer entirely and wire inputs/outputs to the physical I/Os on the board. This has the advantage of not requiring your design to operate as a state machine.

Comment: You literally mean implementing the UART using the FPGA, is that right?

Comment: @user8469759 Correct. A simple UART receiver can be implemented in a few dozen lines of HDL.

Comment: like the stuff here? https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/module-uart-serial-port-rs232.html how can I test this easily? I mean in the fpga actually. Also do I need a C program to pass the data?

Comment: You are attempting something that takes a significant technical background, apparently without a solid footing.  It would be worth your time to get a step-by-step book on Verilog or VHDL and read it, or watch one of the youtube video series on getting started with FPGAs.  You are missing too much basic information for us to be of much help to you here.

Comment: All right, I'll come back to this question later then.

Comment: Hi, I'm following this tutorial : https://youtu.be/7xJ9dhVDCwU?t=3m32s, however I cannot understand what to do in that specific part. What should I do exactly?

Comment: @user8469759 That tutorial isn't quite applicable to your board. You'll need to adapt it a bit. I thought you said you had prior experience with FPGA design??

Comment: As I said I haven't touched this stuff in ages. I bought that board and I'm starting some personal project. I got it is not applicable to my case just try to understand what to adapt, though it seems to me it's a matter of pin mapping I'm missing. I might be wrong though.